# htaccess is supposed to remove index.php from current URL, but instead redirects to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've read been reading StackOverflow posts for the last 30 minutes and none of them work. Maybe there is a server setup that is preventing this from working?

I just want to remove index.php from whatever URL is typed in. For example, `www.mysite.com/blah/blah/index.php` would become `www.mysite.com/blah/blah/`. `www.mysite.com/index.php` would become `www.mysite.com/`.

I've read at least 10 posts and tried each one, but it ALWAYS just redirects to the root. Here is the current code I'm using that looks like it should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Instead of just removing index.php from the URL, it redirects to the root of the site.

Comment: The answers you've been given are valid. The problem is not with the code you've given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1/index.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This still just goes directly to the root.

Comment: Clear your client side cache and retry. Also tell us where that `.htaccess` style file is located.

Comment: Clearing the cache worked! WTF? Why in the world would Chrome be caching server redirects?

Comment: Well, why shouldn't it? It caches every reply it gets where nothing is mentioned about not caching. Makes sense to me. Why should it consider such a redirect _not_ to be permanent?

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This still just goes directly to the root.